# CSS Flex-Boxes: Do not Collapse Centered Content

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center a div with flex boxes, but don't want it to collapse.

```
#forum {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.forum__layout__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

here the HTML ...

```
<div id="forum">
  <div class="forum__layout__container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem: `forum__layout__container` collapses. I want it to fill the screen.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Thanks for your attempts, but my problem is my `max-width` ... It makes my container collapse, which I don't desire !

Comment: _I want it to fill the screen._, horizontally or vertical, or both?

Answer (score 1):

To use the whole screen for a column, you need to specify the height. When then using justify-content, the flexbox will automatically spread the content.

```css
#forum {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.forum__layout__container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 960px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="forum">
  <div class="forum__layout__container">
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
    <p>Text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try justify-content: space-between; That will not use blank space at the start and finish of the column.

Comment: It doesn't fill the 960px ... :(